# any downsides to early spark plug changes?

Tags: engine, sparkplugs, small-engine, spark

Are there any downsides to early spark plug changes? some say 10k 15k etc and some do it as early as 5k =S but would it be okay to get into the habit of changing them after each oil change (6k) miles or am I going to get any problems doing it this soon.

I'm talking about standard plugs, none of that platnium or iridium type stuff.

Comment: Related: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26785/is-it-necessary-to-replace-functioning-spark-plugs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Other than the hole in your pocketbook.

On a separate note, though ... if you are going out of your way to purchase all of those spark plugs, you'd be better off just getting the platinum or iridium plugs which last much longer. For half as much again, you can get a plug which will last several times longer. Some of them will even boost performance over your stock plug. Considering most newer engines have spark plugs which are good for 100k miles, it makes sense to at least consider this.

**EDIT:** One other thing to consider, especially for engines with aluminum heads. Every time you take the spark plug in and out of the threads, you are wearing them out just a little bit more. It is not unheard of for aluminum threads to completely strip out. The usual fix for this is to Heli-Coil the hole, which can be done while the head is on the engine, but a lot of care and time must be given to do it right without getting a lot of debris into the cylinder.

Comment: The type of mileage you do won't make a difference will it whether it be motorway or urban?

Comment: @ceefax12 - If you are strictly considering longevity of the spark plug, driving on the motorway or urban will not have an affect.

Answer (score 4):

You dont need to change them that often as 5k that would just be useless. what @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 said about the aluminum heads is perfectly right. Change them along with your timing chain or water pump.

you have to really careful when changing them. 
Don't over tighten the spark plugs, don't use any dropped spark plugs. screw them in using a 16 inch socket and and extension with hand all the way in and only turn about quarter to half a turn after they are tight with a ratchet.

You can read this: http://www.motoringabout.com/when-to-change-spark-plugs/

http://allaboutautomotive.com/blog/how-often-should-i-have-my-spark-plugs-replaced/